# How to get a selected Id out of a <cfgrid>

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Any help? I have spent hours now looking for how to do this but havent found anything. Most things I have found were a bit too complicated for me you understand.

[image: My CFGRID]

I have this Grid. I would like the user to be able to select a row then press a button either in the grid on outside. When the button is pressed the FormID of the selected row is passed to another cfm to send an email.

If anyone could point me to some where I can learn this or if some here knows and could explain it to me that would be great.

Thanks, 
Will

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you are looking to do is to use the href and hrefkey attributes of the cfgrid.  You would not have them select a button, but when they click on a row they would be sent to the page you set in the href attribute, and the hrefkey attribute would be passed as a url variable called CFGRIDKEY.

Hope this helps.

```
                href="#CGI.script_name#/#REQUEST.URL#/FORM/"
                hrefkey="program_id"
                highlighthref="no"
```